# Having trouble positioning div layer on top of html slider

Tags: css, image, html, slider

I am trying to position an image on top of my slider using this:

CSS:

```
#orbitDemo { background: url(../../images/orbit/spinner.gif) no-repeat center center 
#3c3c3c; height: 300px;  }
#orbitDemo.orbit { height: auto; }
#orbitDemo img, #orbitDemo div { display: none; }
#orbitDemo.orbit img, #orbitDemo.orbit div { display: block;}

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

dl.nice.tabs.mobile { margin-bottom: 0px; }
.nice.tabs.mobile dd a { padding: 12px 20px; }
div.foundation-header h1 { font-size: 32px; font-size: 3.2rem; }
}

#container 
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 950px;
padding: 5px 15px 20px 15px;
border: 1px solid;
border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
border-right: 1px solid #BBB;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 2px #ccc;
background: #fff;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#image
{
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 2000; // might need to be changed if you cant see it
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sliderbg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">           
            <div id="orbitDemo">

        <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $link1; ?>" >
            <img src="<?php echo $slide1 ;?>" alt="Slider" />
        </a>
        </div>

        <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $link2; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide2 ;?>" alt="Slider" />
        </a>
        </div>

        <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $link3; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide3 ;?>" alt="Slider" />
        </a>
        </div>

        <div id="image">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide0 ;?>" (This is the image over the slider.)
        </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(window).load(function() {
$('#orbitDemo').orbit({
     animation: 'horizontal-push',
     bullets: false,
 });
 });
 });
```

This works great. I haven't had any problems with it except that it renders the image I want on top of everything as another side at the end. Am I going about this the wrong way? How can I get it to skip this image or rewrite it so that it doesn't look like another slide?

Comment: Can you give any example of what are you expect?

Comment: I can't find an example but basically it is an image slider with one image over it (maybe a logo) that doesn't move as the images slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

What I should have done is ended the slider div layer and defining the new one with my image over the slider, outside of the slider, then telling it to offset itself based on the slider like this:

```
<div id="sliderbg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">           
            <div id="orbitDemo">


        <a href="<?php echo $link1; ?>" >
            <img src="<?php echo $slide1 ;?>" alt="Slider" />
        </a>



        <a href="<?php echo $link2; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide2 ;?>" alt="Slider" />
        </a>



        <a href="<?php echo $link3; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide3 ;?>" alt="Slider" />
        </a>

     </div>

        <div id="image">
            <img src="<?php echo $slide0 ;?>"
        </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var ob = $('#orbitDemo').offset();
$('#image').css({ 'top': ob.top+56, 'left': ob.left+0 }).show();

$(window).load(function() {
$('#orbitDemo').orbit({
     animation: 'horizontal-push',
     bullets: true,
 });
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I know what you mean but I think you can add position: fixed to your image (for examle logo), and positioning it with top, bottom, right and left.

Comment: Www.ostmosis.com here's a site that does it. Can I fix that image without adding it as another slide?

Comment: So why you add a 'display: none' to your image style?

Comment: I just had it at some point And it didn't seem to affect anything? Could that be what's wrong with it?

Comment: If it have display: none it isn't displaying.

Comment: It is displaying though.. That's what I meant by it doesn't seem to actually be doing anything.

Comment: So i think i cant help you, sorry